# Merge between Git repositories with different history without getting the history from the other repo

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset

I have two git repos `closed` and `open`. I created cloned `open` from `closed` and squashed all commits into one:

```
$ git rev-list --max-parents=0 --abbrev-commit HEAD
ffa625c
$ git reset --hard ffa625c
$ git merge --squash HEAD@{1}
$ git commit
$ git reset --soft "HEAD^"
$ git commit --amend
$ git gc --aggressive
```

`open` is a public GitHub repo, `closed` is a private GitHub repo. Now I develop something in `closed` (with all its git history). When I merge the new feature into `open` I also get all history from `closed`.

How can merge without polluting `open` with the history of `closed`?

**Background:** I have a git repo `closed` with closed source code (containing closed source libraries). Now I got rid of all closed source libraries and I would like to open source my code but I want also to have the closed source repo with all its history to make some closed source additions later on which will be merged to the public repository at some point.

Comment: you can try `git cherry-pick` the specific commits: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Yes that would work but is a bit tedious if I have to merge lots of commits

Comment: You try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch

Comment: What's wrong with `merge --squash`?

Comment: [This StackOverflow-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5724782/80480) which uses `orphan` branches could be a solution.